# Sample HTML placed in a variable

Tags: vb.net

I can retrieve the contents of a webpage into a variable like:

```
x = objIE.Document.body.outerHTML
```

But during development (data parse), I don’t want to keep pulling up a live site and instead just want to store some sample html in a format that can be placed in a variable. The issue is that trying to directly place a raw html sample into a variable creates errors and would require going through and escaping quotes etc. What’s an easy way to put place a large block of sample html in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the html into a string variable using IO.StreamReader

```
    Dim docStuff As String
    Dim strReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strWriter As IO.StreamWriter

    strReader = New IO.StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "/me.html")
    docStuff = strReader.ReadToEnd
    strReader.Close()
```

then write it back out using IO.StreamWriter

```
    strWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "/changedCode.html")
    strWriter.Write(docStuff)
    strWriter.Close()
```

I have never had issues with this method with escape characters, etc.  I pull it in, then I can look at the code, make changes, etc.  Works like a charm.